# facebook permission dialog doesn't show all the required permission

Tags: facebook

We're lately facing a weird bug - when users registered to our site (by their facebook account) they required to confirm the app required permissions, but though we ask for User & Friend Permissions (email and user_location), the permission dialog shows only request of the basic permissions. When clicking on the "Preview Auth Dialog" link in the admin panel the dialog looks great, but in the real world our users don't get the full list of the permissions we require.

Also, the "Default Activity Privacy" are the user default settings though it should appear as "Friends" (as set in the app permissions).

Did anyone faced this problem? (added screen shots of the disaster)

[image: this is how it looks in the preview]
[image: and this is how it looks in the real world]
[image: permission settings]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing Authenticated Referrals with normal login (triggered by your app itself).

Authenticated Referrals is a feature, that ensures all traffic coming to your app directly from Facebook (user clicks on links to go to your app, etc.) will already be authenticated.

The permissions you specify in your app settings are for those and those alone – if you handle login yourself, you have to ask for permissions the usual way, via the scope parameter.

(Facebook recently announced that Authenticated Referrals are deprecated and will be removed shortly, because it was confusing users to much. Even more confusing it seems to be to developers, because this “problem” has come up quite a lot before.)

Comment: CBroe, I'm wondering - you said that authenticated referrals are being deprecated - does that mean we won't be able to have people sign up immediately from within facebook without going through our landing page?

Comment: See https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/10/10/growing-quality-apps-with-open-graph/: _“Authenticated referrals create an inconsistent experience for people by asking them to give permissions in order to access content with little context. You must migrate to use a standard Auth Dialog experience.”_

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this through code.. for e.g.

$url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
            'req_perms' => 'publish_stream,email,friends_location',
            'next' =>$next,
            'cancel_url' =>$cancel_url
             ));